# How do I check my php and pear version using C programming in Linux?

Tags: php, c, linux, pear

If possible, I don't want to use string detection method where you use string functions to detect the version in a given string output. If it isn't possible then please disregard what I just typed.

Is there a function to do it like uname() or do I have to write my own function? If so, please give me a headstart or you can make my life easier by teaching me how to do it. Thanks!

Btw, I'm using dreamhost shared server if that might help and yes, it has gcc, php5.3 and pear 1.9.4 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but that is what you will need to do. The `popen` function is your friend. Simply call "pear -V" in read mode with `popen` and store the information in a buffer that you can easily parse to isolate the version numbers for both pear and PHP. It can be done much cleaner, but the gist of it is:

```
FILE *pfd;
char buffer[1024];
char *bp = buffer;
char tmp[100];
size_t len;
size_t line = 0;

if ((pfd = popen ("pear -V", "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to open pipe.");
    return 1;
}

while (fgets (tmp, 1023, pfd) != NULL && line < 2)
{
    len = strlen (tmp);
    strncpy (bp, tmp, len);
    bp += len;
    line++;
}

pclose (pfd);

printf ("\nbuffer:\n\n%s\n\n", buffer);
```

Output:

```
buffer:

PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.8
```

The parsing of the version numbers is left for you.

Comment: thanks man. I'm still hoping someone out there will pop out with other answers.

Comment: While you are waiting, replace the while loop with `char *pear = fgets (tmp, 1023, pfd); char *php = fgets (tmp, 1023, pfd); char *pearver = strrch (pear, ' '); char *phpver = strrchr (php, ' ');` and at least you will have the versions in pearver and phpver :)